# Discard contractions from string

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have a special use case where I want to discard all the contractions from the string and select only words followed by alphabets which do not contain any special character.

For eg:

```
string = "~ ASAP ASCII Achilles Ada Stackoverflow James I'd I'll I'm I've"
string.scan(/\b[A-z][a-z]+\b/)

#=> ["Achilles", "Ada", "Stackoverflow", "James", "ll", "ve"]
```

Note: It's not discarding the whole word `I'll and I've`

Can someone please help how to discard the whole word which contains contractions?

Comment: `\b` is "word boundary" and it means a transition from a word character (letters, digits, underscore) to a non-word character (not in the previous list) or vice-versa. An apostrophe (`'`) in the middle of a word matches `\b` on both its sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=^))[a-zA-Z]+(?=\s|$)
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=^))` - finds the position immediately preceded by either start of the line or by a white-space
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - matches 1+ occurrences of a letter
- `(?=\s|$)` - The substring matched above must be followed by either a whitespace or end of the line

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1BK4LW/1)

**Update:**

To make sure that not all the letters are in upper case, use the following regex:

```
(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=^))(?=\S*[a-z])[a-zA-Z]+(?=\s|$)
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1BK4LW/2)

The only thing added here is `(?=\S*[a-z])` which means that there must be atleast one lowercase letter

Comment: Thank @Gurman, what if I also want to discard words which are whole uppercase?

eg: ASAP, MIT, IIT, etc..

Comment: `\A` and `\z` are _start of string_ and _end of string_ respectively. Not `^` and `$` which are _start of line_ and _end of line_ respectively.

Comment: @SagarPandya You are correct. I have corrected the statements

Comment: any reason to use `(?<=\s)|(?<=^)` instead of `(?<=\s|^)` and `(?:` is not needed too.. also, keep in mind that the demo link is for `pcre`.. there are many differences compared to `ruby` implementation...

Comment: @Sundeep Actually I was testing this in notepad++ initially where `(?<=\s|^)` gave an error. But, you are absolutely correct. [For ruby, `(?<=\s|^)(?=\S*[a-z])[a-zA-Z]+(?=\s|$)` would work](http://rubular.com/r/67dGhJck56)

Comment: oh ok.. another solution would be `(?<=\s|^)[A-Z]*[a-z][a-zA-Z]*(?=\s|$)`

Answer (score 0):

I know that there's an accepted answer already, but I'd like to give my own shot:

```
(?<=\s|^)\w+[a-z]\w*
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/dwSg7h/4). This regex is shorter and more efficient (157 steps against 315 from the accepted answer).

The explanation is rather simple:

- `(?<=\s|^)`- This is a positive look behind. It means that we want strings preceded by a whitespace character or the start of the string.
- `\w+[a-z]\w*` - This one means that we want strings composed by letters only (word characters) containing least one lowercase letter, thus discarding words which are whole uppercase. Along with the positive look behind, the whole regex ends up discarding words containing special characters.

**NOTE**: this regex won't take into account one-letter words. If you want to accomplish that, then you should use `\w*[a-z]\w*` instead, with a little efficiency cost.